# ¿Donde están todas las preguntas?

Tags: bug, barra-de-navegación

Este es un typo en la nueva navegación. Como se ve en la imagen, dice "Toas las preguntas" (falta la `d`). Para encontrar el error, ir a: Preguntas -> Sin responder

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Te referís a *toas*, *toítas* las preguntas? -¡Yo incluso me preguntaba dónde habían metido a "sin responder"!.. Ojalá sea la antesala de que incluyan la *[new-nav](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/new-nav/info)* de SO.

Comment: Suena a _vocabulario_ [andaluz](https://books.google.es/books?id=Zv36M_8NKUUC&pg=PT14&lpg=PT14&dq=toas+est%C3%A1n+ahi&source=bl&ots=dYnHqOHzu0&sig=SVzgsbVl2iXzVVpHi_HGWT5CIoc&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2hq-XzZ_UAhWEDRoKHY5HB6wQ6AEINzAD#v=onepage&q=toas%20est%C3%A1n%20ahi&f=false)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

¡Esto se ha corregido! Ahora debe decir "todas las preguntas" - esperen unas 2 horas después de la publicación de esta respuesta para que el cambio sea activado.